# 'boolean android.util.SparseBooleanArray.get(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to delete the selected checked items but am getting this error from the code. Please help.

```
                submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //set action after clicking submit
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {        //delete checked items and refresh
                    SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = lview.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    int itemCount = lview.getCount();

                    for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                        if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                            adapter.remove(hangerlist.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    checkedItemPositions.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    for (int i = 0; i < lview.getChildCount(); i++) {        //remove checkbox after deleting
                        lview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkDelete).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);      //remove submit and cancel button after deleting

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = lview.getCheckedItemPositions();

This line returns a null SparseBooleanArray.
You need to check if your list view has 'checked item positions', try adding a breakpoint or posting more code of where you are initializing your lView components.

Comment: yes, you were right. I did not set the choiceMode when i were initializing the listview in xml. Thanks